# How do I limit the action of an OUTPUT clause in a MERGE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

Here's my query:

```
MERGE INTO [payments_orders] o USING (
    SELECT 1 AS [order_id], 50.00 AS [amount] UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 AS [order_id], 50.00 AS [amount]
) AS t ([order_id], [amount]) 
ON o.[payment_id] = 4 AND o.[order_id] = t.[order_id] 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET o.[amount] = t.[amount] 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ([payment_id], [order_id], [amount]) 
VALUES (4, t.[order_id], t.[amount]) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND o.[payment_id] = 4 THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT $ACTION AS [action], [deleted].[order_id];
```

I'm running a MERGE statement to insert or update which order records are associated with which payment records and how that payment is allocated.

**What I want to do** is add `WHERE $ACTION = 'DELETE'` at the end; however that doesn't work. Apparently you can't use a `WHERE` clause within an `OUTPUT` clause; that's "incorrect syntax."

How do I make it so the only rows output from this statement are the ones triggered by the `DELETE`?

Comment: You might have better luck keeping them as separate statements. Your current code doesn't protect you from concurrency / race conditions anyway. [Please read this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thank you for that.  I've never read it (never have used MERGE much anyway)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into the same problem. My solution so far (unless I come up with another one) is to insert dummy values into a temp table for the inserted rows, then clean up the table after the merge statement is done.

```
CREATE TABLE #deleted_orders (order_id int)

MERGE INTO [payments_orders] o USING (
    SELECT 1 AS [order_id], 50.00 AS [amount] UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 AS [order_id], 50.00 AS [amount]
) AS t ([order_id], [amount]) 
ON o.[payment_id] = 4 AND o.[order_id] = t.[order_id] 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET o.[amount] = t.[amount] 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ([payment_id], [order_id], [amount]) 
VALUES (4, t.[order_id], t.[amount]) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND o.[payment_id] = 4 THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT ISNULL([deleted].[order_id], -1) INTO #deleted_orders


DELETE FROM #deleted_orders WHERE order_id=-1
```

Note: You'll need to check on performance, and decide if this change will cause an acceptable performance hit for your use case. Temporary tables can decrease performance: See the section on 'Temporary Tables' [here for T-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647793.aspx#scalenetchapt14%20_topic7)

EDIT: I actually ended up doing something a little different, but fairly similar. It saves you the DELETE step at the end

```
INSERT INTO #deleted_orders (order_id)
        SELECT mrg.order_id
        FROM ( MERGE INTO [payments_orders] o USING (
                    SELECT 1 AS [order_id], 50.00 AS [amount] UNION ALL 
                    SELECT 2 AS [order_id], 50.00 AS [amount]
                ) AS t ([order_id], [amount]) 
                ON o.[payment_id] = 4 AND o.[order_id] = t.[order_id] 
                WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET o.[amount] = t.[amount] 
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ([payment_id], [order_id], [amount]) 
                VALUES (4, t.[order_id], t.[amount]) 
                WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND o.[payment_id] = 4 THEN DELETE 
                OUTPUT [deleted].[order_id] INTO #deleted_orders
OUTPUT $action as MergeAction, deleted.order_id) AS mrg 
WHERE mrg.MergeAction = 'DELETE'
```

Comment: Wessie, I ended up doing something very similar to this. However, to avoid any inconsistencies I just added a permanent table (rather than using temporary tables).

Comment: @alexwweston, Thank You. I also had a similar problem. One more follow up question please, I'm updating columns for both the WHEN MATCHED and WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE scenario, is there anyway to capture the updated records of WHEN MATCHED clause only. when using  action='UPDATE', I'm getting the records of both the clauses.